# Find text between tags in XML files and copy this text to another set of tags in the same file

Tags: xml, perl

I have a bunch of xml files where text in a particular tag was translated that should not have been. Luckily, the same text (untranslated) exists in a prior tag.

The correct text is in

```
 <tcm:Title>Correct Text</tcm:Title>
```

so can be copied and pasted as a replacement.

The tag text to be replaced is

```
 <productService>Incorrect Text</productService>.
```

I am obviously new to Perl so specific code to implement this to a large quantity of files would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use XML::XSH2 for XML processing.

Working on this file:

```
<r>
 <correct>untranslated</correct>
 <incorrect>translated</incorrect>

 <correct>untranslated2</correct>
 <incorrect>translated2</incorrect>
</r>
```

The script then does:

```
open file.xml ;
for //incorrect cp preceding-sibling::correct[1]/text() replace text() ;
```

Comment: Choroba - many apologies, I hadn't noticed that my tag marks went missing from the question as I didn't put them on separate lines in the question. Please read again. Thanks!

Comment: Hm. The relative position of the tags is still unclear. The namespace prefix makes the solution a bit uglier, you have to `register-namespace` first.

Comment: use strict;

use warnings;
use File::Find;
my $doctype = 'xml';
my $startdir = './';

my($s_Source)="test.xml";
open(IN,"<$s_Source") or die "$!";
foreach (map {/<tcm:Title>(.*?)</? ($1) : ()} (<IN>)) {
  print $_,"\n";
  my $found=$_;
  print $found,"\n";

find(
sub{
return unless (/\.$doctype$/i);
local @ARGV = $_;
local $^I = '.bac';
while( <> ){
if( s/<productService>(.*?)</<productService>$found</ig ) {
print;
}
else {
print;
}}}, $startdir);
print "Finished";
   };
close(IN);

Comment: As you can see, I can now open a file, find the correct text and load it into $found. I can then open another file and replace the incorrect text with $found. I have 5000 xml's that all have this problem and that all only have 1 occurance of the correct and incorrect text.